# How to find the distribution of $N(B)|N(A)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a homogeneous Poison process on $R^d$ with intensity $\mu>0$ and $B\subset A\subset R^d$. Assume that the area size of $A$ is $|A|=5$ and the area of $B$ is $|B|=2$.

Question: I try to find the distribution of $N(B)|N(A)$.

---

The definition of $N(A)$ is that (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process)
$$
P(N(B)=n)=\frac{(\lambda |B|)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda|B|}
$$
where  $|B|$ is the volume of $B$ on $R^d$.

How to find the conditional distribution? It seems that we need to find
$$
P(N(B)=m|N(A)=n)=\frac{P(N(B)=m,N(A)=n)}{P(N(A)=n)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{P(N(B)=m, N(A)=n)}{P(N(A)=n)}&=\frac{n!e^{\lambda|A|}P(N(B)=m, N(A\setminus B)=n-m)}{(\lambda|A|)^n}\\
&=\frac{n!e^{\lambda|A|}P(N(B)=m)P(N(A\setminus B)=n-m)}{(\lambda|A|)^n}\\
&\hspace{2em} \text{(by independence)}\\
&=\frac{n!e^{\lambda|A|}e^{-\lambda|B|}e^{-\lambda|A\setminus B|}(\lambda|B|)^m(\lambda|A\setminus B|)^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!(\lambda|A|)^n}\\
&={n\choose m}\frac{|B|^m (|A|-|B|)^{n-m}}{|A|^n}\\
&={n\choose m}\frac{2^m3^{n-m}}{5^n}
\end{align}
when $\ |A|=5\ $ and $\ |B|=2\ $.

Comment: Thanks! But the question is about the distribution function?

Comment: But isn't that what I've calculated—namely the quantity you say that "It seems we need to find"?  I didn't notice, however, that you'd given specific values of $\ 5\ $ and $\ 2\ $ for $\ |A|\ $ and $\ |B|\ $. I've now completed the calculation by substituting those values into the general formula.

Comment: I am not sure. It seems that the question asked that $P(N(B)\le m|N(A)=n)$?

Comment: The term "distribution" is ambiguous. It could refer to any of the probability mass function, the cumulative distribution function or the probability measure $\ P(N(B)\in  X\,|\,N(A))\ $ for $\ X\subseteq\{0,1,\dots,n\}\ $. Since you wrote down the formula for the first, I presumed that it's the one you were asking for.  If you don't know how to calculate the cumulative distribution function from the probability mass function, I'm afraid I'm not prepared to do it for you.

Comment: That is ok. I have got it! Thank you!